# Is there a way to escape special characters with coding applied only in the URL query string?

Tags: javascript, url, parameter-passing, textarea, field

The element in question is a textarea form field. The query string I have added to the URL works fine everywhere but the textarea. If I input "Life is hard" in the textarea field of form one, it populates the textarea field in the target form thus: "Life%20is%20hard" Is there any way to escape the spaces after or as they are appended WITHOUT coding anything outside plugin UX? Like, right there in the query string or the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The content of the query string is **always** URI-encoded, which means that when using it, you **always** have to URI-decode it. Assuming your query string is using the usual `name=value&name=value` form:

```
const entries = queryString.split("&").map(
    entry => entry.split("=").map(
        part => decodeURIComponent(part)
    )
);
```

`entries` is now an array of `[key, value]` arrays with the contents of the query string, properly decoded for use (such as filling in a `textarea`).

Example:

```js
const queryString = "this=that&a=b&text1=Life%20is%20good&x=y";

const entries = queryString.split("&").map(
    entry => entry.split("=").map(
        part => decodeURIComponent(part)
    )
);
for (const [name, value] of entries) {
    if (name === "text1") {
        document.getElementById(name).value = value;
    } else {
        console.log(`Value for ${name}: ${value}`);
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text1"></textarea>
```

If the query string **isn't** in `name=value` form, if it's just purely what you want in the textarea, it's rather simpler:

```
theTextArea.value = decodeURIComponent(queryString);
```

Example:

```js
const queryString = "Life%20is%20good";

document.getElementById("text1").value = decodeURIComponent(queryString);
```

```html
<textarea id="text1"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let's try this. What is wrong with the following string (textarea only) https://yourawesomesite.wpmudev.host/create-profile?name-1={name-1}&name-2={name-2}&email-1={email-1}&url-1={url-1}&textarea-1=decodeURIComponent{textarea-1}

Comment: PS. The above string works for all fields except textarea.

Comment: @documentguy - You can't have function calls in query strings.

Answer (score 0):

The url will be encoded by itself, %20 is that how is work.

Short way:

```
decodeURI(str)
```

or try with:

```
document.write(unescape(str))
```